# LinearLayout not shown as per Height="match_parent" in item_list xml of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `item_list.xml` of `ListView` in side of Activity
Layout shown perfect in Graphical Layout

here put item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5F8295" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/android_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/compliance"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoofTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Other Details for User"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtExtraDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Extra Description"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/compliance"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/empty" // transparent png image 10x10
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**It shown in screen as per below image**

[image]

**I want output as per below image**

[image]

I dont understand why my color layout not showing its height = `"match_parent"`

Comment: what and where is your problem

Comment: Problem is in right side of view.. see images

Comment: i think linearlayout midle 1 properties android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/compliance" may disturb u.

Comment: why you use imageView in it?

Comment: I want to just any color block which height is match_parent but it is not apply on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your layout to some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rightBg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FF0000" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#5F8295" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/compliance"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoofTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Other Details for User"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtExtraDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Extra Description"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you need to change background color of rightBg id in your getView() method

result:
   [image]